# Using a button and then showing dynamic text

Tags: android, eclipse

I am writing a program that when the user enter a number text appears according to that number. My problem is that the button line has public void ... after this I am trying to use if statements and return methods, but because of the public void, the return method can not return anything. I tried to close the public void, but I am getting errors. Please help.
The code is as follows. I have included the different codes that I have tried like toast, etc..

```
ente@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go);
  button.setOnClickListener(mAddListener);

//  tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}

private OnClickListener mAddListener = new OnClickListener()
{ 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        }}
    ;
        //Toast.makeText(Num.this, "This Display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //toast.show();
        //finish ();
    //  long id = 0;
```

// try
   {
      PleaseEnter=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.PleaseEnter);

```
  { 
  }

  if (PleaseEnter.equals("1")) 
     // tv.setText("This is the display 1.");
      return "This display";

   //   Context context = getApplicationContext();
     // CharSequence text ="this display";
 // int duration =Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
 // Toast toast =Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    //    toast.show();
else if  (PleaseEnter.equals("2"))
    return;
    //tv.setText("Dispaly 2");
```

Comment: Why dont you save that text in some string on button click and use it? why do you want  that function to return?

Comment: Why do you want to return it? You can just set the text to the desired component.
I see that you already tried to do it here-tv.setText("This is the display 1.");
Didn't it work?

Comment: @Seshu, did you mean the same thing as Justas
the tv.setText, did not work.

Comment: nope, i meant something like str="This is the display1";

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own method at Activity level, such as:

```
private void onTextEdited(String content) {
    // deal with the String
}
```

In the `onClick` method of your `OnClickListener`, you can call it such as:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PleaseEnter);
    onTextEdited(myEditText.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: I am trying to follow what you wrote, but I am not sure where to put the first line, or what to take out and replace the first line 
private void onTextEdited(String content)

Comment: You can write the first method at Activity level. Then, in this method, you can display the Toast you want, or else set a specific text in a TextView, etc.